# Finding the Fixed Points of an Iterative Map 

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fixed-point-iteration

I need to find fixed points of iterative map `x[n] == 1/2 x[n-1]^2 - Mu`.
My approach:

```
Subscript[g, n_ ][Mu_, x_] :=  Nest[0.5 * x^2 - Mu, x, n]

fixedPoints[n_] := Solve[Subscript[g, n][Mu, x] == x, x]

Plot[
  Evaluate[{x, 
   Table[Subscript[g, 1][Mu, x], {Mu, 0.5, 4, 0.5}]}
  ], {x, 0, 0.5}, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer right now - but have a look at this old [physicsforums thread](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=448090).

Comment: please learn to use [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), the input language used to format questions and answers here. Also, when giving a code example, try to remove any unnecessary pieces, like the `FrameLabels` in this case, as it tends to hide what you're asking for. Lastly, what exactly are you looking for here? Does your code work, or not? Is it to slow? What else have you tried? Please be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll change notation slightly (mostly so I myself can understand it). You might want something like this.

```
y[n_, mu_, x_] := Nest[#^2/2 - mu &, x, n]
fixedPoints[n_] := Solve[y[n, mu, x] == x, x]
```

The salient feature is that the "function" being nested now really is a function, in correct format.

Example:

```
fixedPoints[2]

Out[18]= {{x -> -1 - Sqrt[-3 + 2*mu]}, 
          {x -> -1 + Sqrt[-3 + 2*mu]}, 
          {x ->  1 - Sqrt[ 1 + 2*mu]}, 
          {x ->  1 + Sqrt[ 1 + 2*mu]}}
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: @Mr. Nahh. I'm just short sighted. I can't read code in the default SO text font.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is an error in your approach. Nest takes a pure function. Also I would use exact input, i.e. 1/2 instead of 0.5 since Solve is a symbolic rather than numeric solver.

```
Subscript[g, n_Integer][Mu_, x_] := Nest[Function[z, 1/2 z^2 - Mu], x, n]
```

Then

```
In[17]:= fixedPoints[1]

Out[17]= {{x -> 1 - Sqrt[1 + 2 Mu]}, {x -> 1 + Sqrt[1 + 2 Mu]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A side note:

Look what happens when you start very near to a fixed point (weird :) :

```
f[z_, Mu_, n_] := Abs[N@Nest[1/2 #^2 - Mu &, z, n] - z]

g[mu_] := f[1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*mu] - mu 10^-8, mu, 10^4]

Plot[g[mu], {mu, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

In fact, it seems you have an autosimilar structure there:

[image]